# Why is there an apostrophe in "geht’s"?

Tags: apostrophe

Why do we use an apostrophe in *geht’s*?

> Mir geht’s sehr gut, und dir?

Comment: Why is there an apostrophe in "don't"?

Comment: Apostrophe wurde schon hundertmal gefragt, rechts bei 'related' ist schon eine kleine Auswahl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The apostrophe in geht's is a contraction, indicating that a letter is skipped from the formal spelling.

The actual (formal) phrase is:

> Mir geht es sehr gut, und dir?

This spelling actually indicates the common casual pronunciation of the phrase. If you listen carefully you will be able to hear the difference - some people will enunciate the 'es' clearly, while others will not (or the same person will pronounce the 'es' when they speak more formally)

Answer (score 5):

As it would be expected, the apostrophe indicates a contraction. Here, the full phrase in formal German would be:

> Mir geht **es** (sehr) gut, und dir?

(The comma is optional and the strengthener *sehr* is not needed.)

However, practically nobody would ever pronounce *geht’s* as two words — although I even know somebody who would (she always speaks very slowly and clearly). Therefore, outside of wholly written texts (e.g. newspaper articles) or literature that does not attempt to truthfully represent pronunciation of direct speech, this will practically always be shortened. The basis for this is § 97 of the [official spelling rules](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_regeln_inkl_Nachtraegen.pdf):

> Man kann den Apostroph setzen, wenn Wörter gesprochener Sprache mit Auslassungen bei schriftlicher Wiedergabe undurchsichtig sind.

Loosely translated:

> An apostrophe may be typeset, if words with contractions in spoken language are unclear/difficult to read in writing.

Thus, the apostrophe in *geht’s* is actually not mandatory but merely optional. Therefore, you may have seen *gehts* in one place or another instead.